# Why my code is selecting all text() nodes in Htmldocument

Tags: c#, html, parsing, dom

```
    HtmlNode node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr")[0];
            foreach(HtmlTextNode n in node.SelectNodes("//text()"))
               Console.WriteLine(n.Text);
```

HTML:

```
<table class="infobox" style="width: 17em; font-size: 100%;float: left;">
<tr>
<th style="text-align: center; background: #f08080;" colspan="3">خدیجہ مستور</th>
</tr>
<tr style="text-align: center;">
<td colspan="3"><a href="/wiki/%D8%AA%D8%B5%D9%88%DB%8C%D8%B1:Khatijamastoor.JPG" class="image" title="خدیجہ مستور"><img alt="خدیجہ مستور" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/ur/thumb/7/7b/Khatijamastoor.JPG/150px-Khatijamastoor.JPG" width="150" height="203" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/ur/thumb/7/7b/Khatijamastoor.JPG/225px-Khatijamastoor.JPG 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/ur/thumb/7/7b/Khatijamastoor.JPG/300px-Khatijamastoor.JPG 2x"></a><br>
<div style="font-size: 90%">خدیجہ مستور</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th style="background: #f08080;" colspan="3">ادیب</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><b>ولادت</b></td>
<td colspan="2"><a href="/wiki/1930%D8%A1" title="1930ء">1930ء</a>، <a href="/wiki/%D9%84%DA%A9%DA%BE%D9%86%D8%A4" title="لکھنؤ">لکھنؤ</a>، <a href="/wiki/%D8%A8%D8%B1%D8%B7%D8%A7%D9%86%D9%88%DB%8C_%DB%81%D9%86%D8%AF%D9%88%D8%B3%D8%AA%D8%A7%D9%86" title="برطانوی ہندوستان" class="mw-redirect">برطانوی ہندوستان</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><b><a href="/wiki/%D8%A7%D8%B5%D9%86%D8%A7%D9%81_%D8%A7%D8%AF%D8%A8" title="اصناف ادب">اصناف ادب</a></b></td>
<td colspan="2"><a href="/wiki/%D9%86%D8%A7%D9%88%D9%84" title="ناول" class="mw-redirect">ناول</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><b>معروف تصانیف</b></td>
<td colspan="2"><a href="/wiki/%D8%A2%D9%86%DA%AF%D9%86" title="آنگن">آنگن</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Output Should be :

خدیجہ مستور

but i found :

خدیجہ مستور

خدیجہ مستور

ادیب

ولادت

1930ء
، 
لکھنؤ
، 
برطانوی ہندوستان

اصناف ادب

ناول

معروف تصانیف

آنگن

Why node.selectNodes("//text()") is selecting all text() nodes in document rather text() nodes from just first tr tag??

Comment: it looks like you want SelectSingleNode()

Comment: no actually i want text() nodes separately from all tr tags to distinguish some data connection and store it meaningfully. doc.DocumentNode.Select("//tr")[0] should select first tr and then i apply on this tr row to get all text() elements that are children in this tr only.

Comment: gotcha i misread/misunderstood then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are adding two forward slashes to the beginning of your XPath (`//tr`), which selects all of the elements *in the document*, not just descendants of the selected node.

Try this instead:

```
foreach (HtmlTextNode n in node.SelectNodes("text()"))
```

Or just simplify the XPath to:

```
var node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//tr[1]/text()");
Console.WriteLine(node.Text);
```

Comment: this is generating exception instead of System.nullReferenc : reference is not set to any object??

Comment: /text() is generating exception of nullReference and text() is selecting nothing ???

Comment: thanx i got it there was an issue of xpath i was given //tr first that selects all tr nodes in document and then //text() that selects all text() elements in whole document instead **//tr[0]//text()** that is correct path that tells  text() of first or 0th tr in the whole document // means select all nodes in the whole document instead of current othervise give proper path